# Game Physics Engine : Euler integration : why body under gravity is not covering 9.8 meters/second?

Tags: physics, physics-engine, integration, euler-method

I am working on very basic physics engine and I used euler interation which works like below,

```
acceleration = GRAVITY; //9.8 m/s
velocity += acceleration * deltaTime;
position += velocity * deltaTime;
```

but when I calculate how much distance (in meters) it covers in a second. Its less than 9.8 m/s (around 5 meters). Please help me understand what's wrong in this euler integration.

Thanks.

Comment: Acceleration is not speed.

Comment: oh yes its velocity. not the distance. Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the speed of the object after 1 second will be 9.81 m/s.

However it starts at 0 and increases to 9.81 m/s. So all that time in that first second the speed of the object is less than 9.81.

Comment: The average speed over the first second is (9.81 + 0) / 2 = 4.9 m/s, so it will travel 4.9m over that second.